# Really strange white gap on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, web

I know other people have already asked about this before on StackOverflow, but I have been trying to fix this problem for days already with no luck. My website looks great on the computer but when I test it on mobile, a really annoying white space shows up in the right side of the display.

I tried to...

- Set overflow-x: hidden on the body;
- Set overflow-x: hidden on the html (it affected the scroll);
- Set width: 100%, on both body and html;
- I tried removing the navbar, that was apparently overflowing the body, but that didn't solve my problem.

It's like there's a "ghost" lying in that white space, because I also removed all the "padding-left" and "margin-left" from all the elements. Nothing.

Does anyone have a clue?

Here is the link: tomasperone.esy.es.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick fix - add 'overflow: hidden' to the 'container' class.

```
.container, .container-fluid:overflow: hidden;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It didn't. And it doesn't only happend on iPhone.  It happens on Android devices as well. It happens on my Motorola, for example. But thanks anyway.

Comment: As a quick fix - add 'overflow: hidden' to the .container class.

'.container, .container-fluid:overflow: hidden;'

Comment: Thank you!! It worked. For some weird reason, it worked.